# Having issues deleting data from datagridview. Does not update data table information when i delete row. c# visual studios

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017

[image: 1]

Having issues deleting data from datagridview. Button does delete row in the datagridview initially at least from view . However, Does not update data table information when I delete row. Once I reload application the row I deleted previously on datagridview is back. I want code to delete from datagridview as well as update data table. Please help, I don't have much experience with using C#.
C# visual studios 2017.

[image: 2]

```
 private void button6_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            
            {
                

                dataGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView2.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                dataSaving2BindingSource.EndEdit();
               

                MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("nope");
            }
        
            
            
}
```

Comment: How are you binding/populating your datagridview?

Comment: `dataSaving2BindingSource.RemoveCurrent();` if the dataGridView2.DataSource uses dataSaving2BindingSource

Comment: Tried adding the dataSavingBindingSource.RemoveCurrent(); still did not work. still does not update my data table. Also, once i reload application it reappears on my datagridview2.